# Translating the map command and few others from Mathematica to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dictionary, wolfram-mathematica

I did these so far:

EDIT---------------

```
steps=@ (m) 2*randi([0,1],[1,m])-1;
Walk1D =@ (n) [0,cumsum(steps(n))];
findend=@ (x) x(end);
LastPoint1D=@(n) findend(Walk1D(n));

nsteps=200;
nsq=floor(sqrt(nsteps));
MeanSquareDistance1D= @ (n,m) m.*sum((LastPoint1D(n)).^2)./m;
r2D=MeanSquareDistance1D(100,1000)

data=[ ];
for i=10:20:90
data=[data; i , MeanSquareDistance1D(i,2000)]
end
```

The only problem now,is that the 2nd column of "data" must give me values around

```
10
30
50
70
90
```

but not exactly.Only approximately.For example ,the "data" must be:

```
10  10.184
30  27.51
50  50.306
70  68.394
90  90.414
```

Sth is wrong with the sum maybe?

Comment: This previous question may help you: [Map function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983163/map-function-in-matlab)

Comment: Thanks ,i saw this question but my problem is that i can't express the "data" as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I guess you want to calculate the mean squared distance for a 1D random walk.

The mean squared distance at lag `tt` is the average squared difference between two positions along the random walk separated by `tt` steps. I assume that `data` should be an array where the first column is `tt` and the second column the corresponding mean squared distance, and where there is an additional parameter that indicates the total number of steps in your random walk.

Here's how I'd calculate `data`

```
%# define parameters
nSteps = 2000;
listOfLags = 10:20:90; %# must be 1-by-n vector

%# create random walk
%# steps can be +1 or -1, add all of them via cumsum
randomWalk = cumsum(randi([0 2],nSteps)-1);

%# calculate msd for the desired lags
%# use a loop for readability
nLags = length(listOfLags);
data = zeros(nLags,2);
data(:,1) = listOfLags;

for lag = listOfLags
    %# lag takes on every lag value, so use logical indexing to find
    %# which lag (in terms of entry into data) we're currently working on

    %# This line corresponds to
    %# 1. get all distances traveled within a duration of `lag`
    %#    vectorOfDistances = randomWalk(lag+1:end) - randomWalk(1:nSteps-lag)
    %#    i.e. the first element is randomWalk(lag+1)-randomWalk(1)
    %# 2. square all: (vectorOfDistances).^2
    %# 3. average all squared distances 
    data(listOfLags==lag,2) = mean( (randomWalk(lag+1:end) - randomWalk(1:end-lag)).^2);
end

%# plot the results
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'.')
xlabel('lag'),ylabel('mean squared displacement')
```

Comment: First of all thanks again!I have a hard time following your code because i worded it in another way(Walk1D,LastPoint1D ,etc).I am editing my original post in a minute to show you where i got.(I tried your code but gives me "?? Undefined function or variable 'lags'.)

Comment: If you can't help,its ok Jonas,you  have helped me more than enough..You don't have all the time for me :)

Comment: @George: Sorry about the mistake. If you do what I think you want to do, you are most likely doing it wrong, since for a mean squared distance, you have to take the average over a vector of distances, and your `LastPoint1D` returns a scalar, and `m.*()./m` doesn't actually do anything other than waste cycles.

Comment: I must do sth like "(sum((LastPoint(n)-LastPoint(0)).^2))./m" but how?

Comment: I did it like this(with help):
steps1=@ (n, m) randi([-1 1], n, m);
LastPoint_1D=@ (n, m) sum(steps1(n, m));
MeanSquareDistance1D = @(n,m)  mean(LastPoint_1D(n,m).^2);

Answer (score 3):

Although Matlab supports anonymous functions and has rudimentary support for functional programming, it is not particularly well-supported or idiomatic.   The Matlab approach is to instead use vectors (the Matlab name for arrays) wherever possible, and use functions which are evaluated over these vectors.

Instead of

```
Walk1D =@ (n) cumsum(steps(n));
```

which does not work because the argument to `cumsum` (which expects a vector) is simply `steps(n)` (a single element of the vector `steps`!), the idiomatic Matlab approach is to do something like:

```
Nsteps = 100;  
steps = randn(1, Nsteps);
walk1D = cumsum(steps);
```

etc.

If you do need it, the Matlab equivalents to the functional programming "map" operator are [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) and [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html).

(Aside: Matlab's heritage is rooted in Fortran, compared to Mathematica, which is inspired by Lisp.  Anonymous functions in Matlab are limited to simple expressions, so it is often necessary to use a traditional named function stored in a separate .m file. I often feel that the functional programming constructs in Matlab are mostly a novelty, though they are sometimes useful.)

Comment: Hello,the Walk1D function works fine but thanks for the approach you gave me.I have problem with writing the "data"above because i am a bit confused what to write!

Answer (score 2):

I would comment on your Mathematica input a little, suggesting efficiency improvements

```
Walk1D[n_] :=  Join[{0},Accumulate[steps[n]]]
LastPoint1D[n_] := Total[steps[n]]
```

Here are timings showing the difference

```
In[51]:= steps[n_Integer] := RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, n]

In[52]:= Walk1D[n_] := Join[{0}, Accumulate[steps[n]]]

In[53]:= Walk1Da[n_] := FoldList[Plus, 0, steps[n]]

In[56]:= BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; AbsoluteTiming[r = Walk1D[10^7];]]

Out[56]= {0.3650000, Null}

In[57]:= BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; AbsoluteTiming[r = Walk1Da[10^7];]]

Out[57]= {1.1370000, Null}
```